# How would I select and group multiple images from excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm having an issue with Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select, if it's removed I'm left with only the selection of all my images on the active worksheet. I would like to group the images on each worksheet in a single workbook. In this case I have 6 images per worksheet.

What would I need to add/modify for this macro to group the images into one object? I'm using Excel 2010.

```
  Sub GroupShapes()

     Dim Current As Worksheet

     ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
     For Each Current In Worksheets

            Current.Shapes.SelectAll
            Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select

     Next

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub GroupShapes()

   Dim Current As Worksheet

   ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each Current In Worksheets
      Current.DrawingObjects.ShapeRange.Group
   Next

End Sub
```

You don't have to actually select the shapes first. You can act on them directly. It throws an error if there are no shapes, though, so we tell it to keep going anyway with `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! Appreciate the quick response.